# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi]

Tags: java, spring, maven, xsd, osgi

I have following exception during Spring initialization:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi]
Offending resource: OSGi resource[bundleentry://104.fwk32582392/META-INF/varaza/extender/extender-context.xml|bnd.id=103|bnd.sym=com.pearlox.varaza]
```

How can I determine which JAR (which Maven artifact contains definition of proper NamespaceHandler for [http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi] ? What my strategy of fixing this should look like?

What else have I to include into my question to help you understand the situation? (please comment)

P.S.: I see lots of similar questions here on StackOverflow related to other libraries but answer depends on particular namespace.

Comment: Any of the following: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.osgi/spring-osgi-core

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have this in my pom: 

    <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.osgi</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-osgi-core</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: It looks like from your exception that you are using Spring DM - is that correct?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have this problem.

Comment: @Phil Due to this and lot of other OSGi related problems we've decided to remove OSGi from a project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the OSGi namespace, this will only be initialized into a osgi container you can not run it using mvn install.